# Privilege environment in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a .NET windows application (c#) to keep some financial accounts for our customers. The people in my company will be in charge of registering all customer data but they must have different level access. So my question is, what is the best way to grant privileges to users? Let's say some people will have permissions to modify some parameters and others won't. I'm thinking about disabling some controls in the windows forms depending on level privileges but I think this is hardcoding.

What do you think is the best way to achieve this in order to keep performance and scalability?

Comment: Would you prefer to use your company's Active Directory group memberships to manage access or instead maintain a role repository specifically for your app?

Comment: I prefer not to use AD since I'm plannig to distribute this app later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with Control's to set User Privileges ,which i think is fine(i used sometimes to control that),getting User Right's from a DataBase Server or a Service(Web or WCF).
You can make 2 Similar forms where First one is for Administrator and the Second is for the user where user has 2 or 3 button's less than the Administrator,or you it can be a single Form where you can Hide or Show buttons and other Control's through code validator's.
Another way i would prefer is ,Engineering the Software module based.
Build as many DLL Modules as it is possible(it takes more time to code) and than Load or Unload and Validate the Desired Module to a desired User.
And maybe Validating each Method with a Boolean ,would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Cody, I'm thinking about using the same controls for all users and avoid creating a lot of windows forms. Maybe if I store in my DB what controls are accesible for each kind of user privilege I'd get a less coded app, what do you think?

Comment: That probably will be a short cut ,but i think it would be much secure if you provide forms for each user privileges and that will cause more inspection to Attackers or maybe the Attacker will never find out that you have another proper form for Administrator ,that is only for security purpose .

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use the [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) interface from .Net to implement your own privilege system. The IPrincipal provides you with the only method IsInRole() where you can check if the current user is a member of a certain role and maintain the access permissions via roles. You can use [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.aspx) class to get the user roles from local user directory or from AD.

On the other side since you application is extremely data-centric you can just use the user right management of your database server (MS SQL, MySQL etc) to grant access permissions to the users. This is more secure but requires you to manage your server accordingly.

Comment: Privileges will be managed from database but I need to find a relationship between these privileges and my windows form controls

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it, there's nothing inherently wrong with hard-coding security permissions.

I would however double check the permissions in code, even if the button is disabled. It's easy to enable them back externally.